# Should extended question answering be done in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Although not often, I've recently been in a problem when answering questions, by desperate users, looking for a answer.

It (my problem) usually starts like this: I'll begin by asking them to clarify their question in the comments, below their question. They'll answer back and say, so and so. I'll then post my answer to their question, based upon their feedback.

The problem appears when they say my solution/solutions does not work. I'll then ask them more questions depending on their response. Then we go back and forth. He'll say he's got another error or something is not working right, and I'll respond back by asking if he's sure he typed something right or he installed something correctly.

After about eight or nine comments, Stack Overflow will warn me that:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; would you like to move this conversation to chat?

So I pondered whether trying to address the OP's extra errors (still somewhat related to the question) in the comments would be a bad idea. If so, wouldn't it still be a bad idea to tell him to edit his question to include his extra errors. If I or someone else had already answer the original question, him adding error questions would make other answers seem as if they just ignored part of the question or did not answer it in full. More so, it might seem like he was asking multiple questions in his post, which could also be bad/incorrect.'

You of course, have the option of moving the comment conversation to chat, but it seems that this method would be inconveniencing to the answerer if they did not have time or were not in a position to were they could have a full fledged chat.

To make my question clear; Would it be appropriate to attempt to solve some of the OP's errors in the comments if they are still related to their question?

Comment: Will someone that has the same problem as the one the OP is asking in the comments be able to find your comments easily? Don't feed the help vampires. That's not helping the site.

Comment: @DEAD I agree with what your saying about feeding help vampires(and some of my comments probably apply), but should i just stop answering the user if they keep saying that there getting a error, even with using my answers solution?

Comment: If they listened to your advice, and get other, different errors, then they have other problems in their code. That would be irrelevant to the gist of question and the answer(s). It's good if you address further questions of the OP, but only if they're meant to clarify what's in your answer further.

Comment: @UmarAta but wouldn't that be inappropriate if they just came out of the wood works, hours later, asking for a solution to another problem they encountered?

Comment: I really don't think so. If the OP has **already** asked his original question, and you answer addressed that question, they can't just come running back with a completely different error/question, and expect you to change your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple. If the discussion is to clarify the specific problem the OP is having, then:

- Move it to chat
- Complete the discussion there
- Edit the question as needed to reflect the discussion
- Edit your answer to fully articulate the solution

This way no one has to wade through a long discussion in comments - it's all there in the question and answer.

If the discussion is around further issues, or follow-up questions, then no - they should be asked as new questions.